# ng2-idle modal ok should resume idle

Tags: angular, ng2-idle

Angular4 with @ng2-idle trying to capture the inactivity of the user.

code example link
https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/

I am trying to customize it so every time user goes idle i show modal with ok button. and user will able to resume only ok is clicked on the modal.

on page load default interrupts are on

```
idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
```

on `idleStart` i show my modal and count down begins
on `onIdleEnd` i close my modal

when modal is open i want to disable `DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES` only manual interrupt so i called `idle.clearInterrupts()` and on modal ok press event calling `idle.interrupt(true);` 
once modal is close i set `idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);` again.

does not seems to work very well. after modal close and open again it does not car about `DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES` and on `setIdle` time it goes automiticaly `idle` mode even though user interacts with the UI.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing with the same issue , How did you resolved it. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866420/ngidle-how-to-clear-and-reset-interrupts-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your modal is open better to call `idle.stop()` than clearing the `DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES` then on modal close call `idle.watch()`

Comment: No.. this approach wont work if someone wants to show countdown

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
idle.clearInterrupts()
```

to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Moses , I am also stuck on the same issue, In my case clearInterrupts() is working but unable to reset the interrupts . Please check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866420/ngidle-how-to-clear-and-reset-interrupts-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Hi the following worked for me.

On the open modal I clear the interrupts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => this.countdown = countdown);
    this.idle.clearInterrupts();
  }
```

and then when the continue button is clicked I reset the interrupts and start watching the idle again:

```
  continue() {
    this.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
    this.idle.watch();
    this.dialog.close();
  }
```